# How to add JavaScript from Code Behind C#?

Tags: javascript

How do I run this javascript from code behind C# during page load? Thanks a lot and many thanks in advance.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
document.onkeydown = function (event)
{
     event = (event || window.event);
     if (event.keyCode == 20)
     {
          alert('Caps not allow');
     }
}
</script>
```

Comment: Isn't that javascript will already lood on page load? I think we are missing what you are trying to achieve. Can you give more details?

Comment: Is this in ASP.NET? If so, WebForms or MVC?  Something else?

Comment: I am so sorry. What I am trying to achieve is that instead of putting the JavaScript in the HTML page. I would like to load the JavaScript from asp.net webforms code behind using c# during page load. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the RegisterStartupScript method.

Example in c#:

```
private void Page_Load1(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    string js = "document.onkeydown = function (event) { event = (event || window.event); if (event.keyCode == 20) { alert('Caps not allow'); } }";

    ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this.Page, this.GetType(), "capscheck", js, true);
}
```